# How can I set up color profiles in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, images, color-profiles, icc

When doing web design I try and always save JPG images in Photoshop without the color profile embedded, otherwise if they are next to a GIF or PNG image, or even another JPG with no icc profile, or a different icc profile, the browser will render the color differently.

Here is an example, where the hover state of the nav2 item is a different image, and it is showing up with a slightly different background color:

[image]

I have Chrome, Firefox, and Safari installed and they are all rendering this navigation menu just fine for me, but the image above is a client's screenshot using Firefox.

**How can I get my browser to behave like hers?**

I installed the [Color Management](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/color-management/) extension for Firefox. I've tried selecting different options and different profiles.

[image]

However I still can't reproduce the behavior for this particular site. What am I doing wrong?

If I go to [this site](http://www.northlight-images.co.uk/article_pages/web-browser-color-management.html), and look at the first set of images, I can see that they do look different (at least if I'm using the settings in the screenshot above).

[image]

How can I reproduce this odd behavior so I can test for it?

**Update:** This might be related to OS X 10.5 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try enabling ICC version 4.

1. Open a new tab in Firefox and go to `about:config`.
2. Type in `gfx.color_management.enablev4` into the search.
3. Double click on that string to enable it (set it to TRUE).

If that does not reproduce the results, try messing around with the `gfx.color` settings in `about:config`.

Also, open Firefox in Safe Mode (Firefox button -> Help -> Restart with Add-ons Disabled) to see what the default view is.

Finally, make sure that your client is using an up-to-date version of Firefox, since older versions presumably have different quirks and levels of colour profile support. Try testing on another machine to see what it displays.